# How to properly set up python multiprocessing when more processes must be handled than number of cpu's?

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, multiprocessing

I have a project that I am working on to segment images. It does so by evaluation every pair of pixels location and intensity difference (or similarity). It treats each pixel as a node on a graph, and each pixel's similarity corresponds to the weight of its connecting edge. Therefore, I need to build a symmetrical weight matrix of size `(imageHeight*imageWidth)^2`.

This turned out to take a very long time to build the matrix, so I am trying to pralellize it (if that's a word).

Here is the code snippet in question:

```
def Multiprocess(self, sigmaI, sigmaX):
    cpus = mp.cpu_count()
    print('Number of cpu\'s to process WM: %d' % cpus)
    jobs = []
    i = 0
    for p in range(self.numPixels):
        for c in range(cpus):
            if i >= self.numPixels:
                break
            else:
                weightCalculation = mp.Process(name='weightCalc%d'%(i), target = self.CreateMatrixMp, args = (sigmaI, sigmaX, i,))
                jobs.append(weightCalculation)
                weightCalculation.start()
                i += 1
```

Really the only thing you need to know is that `self.numPixels` is the number of pixels in the image. `sigmaX` and `sigmaI` are the variances in position and intensity between any two pixels.

What the algorithm used to do was look at one pixel, pixel `i`, and then loop through every other pixel `j` in the image and find the similarity between them. So it was doing `numPixels^2` operations in concurrency.

What I expect the code that I have written above to do is to do that same thing, but to a `cpus` number of pixels at one time. Now there should be `(numPixels^2)/cpus` processes running in concurrency, correct? For large, even small, images, this should make a significant time reduction.

But is my structuring right? I have to have some kind of loop that continues beyond the number of cpus (the `for p in range(self.numpixels)`). So in that case, does it even matter if I have the line `for c in range(cpus)`? It would do the same thing if it was the while loop by itself, since once it assigns a `cpu` number of processes, it just loops again.

Should I instead have something that "waits" at the end of the for loop, and will only start the next process after one has finished? Or if I leave it as it is, will it just queue them in some way? But that brings me back to wondering if I even need to specify the cpu count anywhere. I guess this is a question of how the multiprocessing python package works, but I have read several tutorials and all the documentation and seem to be missing something.

Thanks to anyone who read all this :P, and to anyone who can help!

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool.  It will take care of distributing the work over a group of processes for you.  You will only need to think about how to move the data and results back and forth.

Comment: @bj0 This doesn't seem to fit my purpose, and has thoroughly confused me. I only say it doesn't fit because the function that each process is calling doesn't anything, it just modifies a list. But both Pool.apply and Pool.map seem to be useful for obtaining lists of result values.

Comment: you don't want to modify a list by multiple processes.  Unless you are using shared memory objects made for that purpose, it will not work.  What I was referring to is the way you are manually splitting up your data and sending it to different processes is done automatically with a Pool.  A Pool also re-uses processes so there is less overhead of creating/destroying procs

Comment: A suggestion: if you're processing lots of images then you might parallel the separate images - run your existing script many times - rather than breaking up the algorithm. It'll be easier and for many images the time savings will be the same or better.

Comment: @bj0 I understand that. But to get the Pool processes to do anything, you have to either call `map` or `apply`, correct? Both of these expect a result returned. Should I make it so that the target function does return a value? It could return a tuple of (intensity, x, y), and the `map` function could put all of those into a big list. since I have the coordinate information, I can go back at the end and do one big write to my data array. Since the coordinate information would be saved as well, I could easily get it back into order. I think I may have answered my own question. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel This will probably only be applied to single images. Perhaps in the future we may want to add parallel image processing when we finish this and move it to out beefy machine; 40 cpus and 200gb memory. I still suspect only one image would be ran at a time, it would just be run very fast.